# Creating dynamic rows inside a column that have other rows using C# in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am new to ASP.net dev using C#.

I want to accomplish the following. Please have a look at the image below.

[image]

The first row of the image '01 - Requirements' will be fixed. Actually my page will have 16 tables like this that will have the first row serving as title fixed. (I can get the titles from the database, or hard code them. No problem both ways as they are not much and will remain fixed in the scope of the project)

Once the user presses the red plus button, he will be able to add sub requirements. Here, the sub requirement can only be a string; such as 'First Requirement' or 'Second Requirement'.

Once there is a Sub Requirement, it can have another sub sub requirement, where the sub sub requirement has many parameters that include drop downs etc as it appears in the image. Also the sub sub divisions may be more than one.

After that, I want to save them into a database. But my concern is not that, rather than making this appear in a nice way for the end user.

What is the best way to do this?
Using tables?
Using grid views that are customized? Can we even do that?
Ajax and jQuery?
Manual programming adding of buttons and labels?

I would appreciate any insight that would pave the way for me to embark on the journey to come out with a very catchy and user friendly design.

Comment: I would use [Telerik Grids](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: @JonathanYanivBenAvraham Telerik is cool... but expensive.

Comment: @James, can you please give some more context as to what frameworks you have access to? (only jQuery only, Angular, React, none of them?)

Comment: I have knowledge in C# for windows desktop dev. and I am building from that and moving to web dev using C# in asp.net. I also know basic jQuery. Absolutely no knowledge of Angular or React. Although I have no problem learning if there is the need to. @RohanBüchner

Answer (score 1):

If you want it super-smooth (no post backs), you want a mixture of

jQuery and ASP.NET MVC

or

Angular.js + WebAPI

I used to do jQuery.  Now I also do Angular.  If you're just starting, I would tilt toward jQuery, since it is a little more straight forward.  But if you want to dive in, then angular is good too.

Below are links...and live demos.

https://superdevelopment.com/2013/12/16/building-rich-web-apps-jquery-vs-angular-js/

And a live demo

http://jquerymvcvsangularwebapitodolist.apphb.com/WebApiAngular/Views/#/todoLists

Comment: Does this work with MVC? because I am reading a tutorial now about ASP.net wihout MVC

Comment: In the article... a section called "jQuery + ASP.NET MVC".  Can you do jQuery without MVC?  Yes.  But you can do it with MVC as well.